# Use Json.Net for input binding of Azure EventGridEvent

Tags: json.net, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid, inputbinding

I currently use `Json.Net` throughout my project and it works like a charm. Unfortunately, the input binding for Azure Functions use `System.Text.Json` to deserialize the EventGrid event json and bind it to`EventGridEvent` object from the `Azure.Messaging.EventGrid 4.0.0.-beta.4` library

have a look here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5469

This causes massive problems as all my custom `JsonConverters` that i have do not work at all which leads to incorrectly deserialized objects. Changing from `Newtonsoft.Json` to `System.Text.Json` is a massive amount of rework and i would absolutely like to avoid that, if i can.

Is there a way to force the input bindings to use `Json.Net` instead of `System.Text.Json`either via DI in `FunctionssStartup.Configure()` or otherwise?

Comment: I am not sure where did you see `System.Text.Json` reference in EventGrid binding. The extension uses `Newtonsoft.Json` AFAIK https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-eventgrid-extension